# Sql FREETEXTTABLE with list searchkey

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, freetexttable

it looks FREETEXTTABLE just allow searchkey parameter as variable, like this:

```
FROM FREETEXTTABLE(dbo.SampleTable, SampleColumn, @searchKey)
```

I have a list searchKey values, about 50000 records, how to "JOIN" searchKey table with FREETEXTTABLE

I've used WHILE but it's very slow

```
DECLARE @results as table(
    Key NVARCHAR(100),
    Rank INT
)

declare @numberOfRows INT = SELECT MAX(Id) FROM dbo.SearchKeyTable)
declare @step int = (SELECT MIN(Id) FROM dbo.SearchKeyTable)

WHILE (@step <= @numberOfRows)
BEGIN
    declare @searchKey NVARCHAR(500) = (Select TOP(1) '''' + REPLACE([Description], '''', '"')  + ''' OR ''' + REPLACE([itemname], '''', '"') + '''' From dbo.SearchKeyTable where id = @step ORDER BY Id)

    insert into @results
    select [Key] as KeyId, SUM([Rank]) as TotalRank FROM FREETEXTTABLE(dbo.SampleTable, SampleColumn, @searchKey) GROUP BY [Key]

    SET @step = @step + 1
END

select * from @results
```

My dbo.SampleTable table is also large, about 16 millions record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current solution: use c# multi-thread to replace WHILE